# How to specify the date format inside create table command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to create a table with the following columns
Emp_no [PK], Basic_pay_fixed_at, Date_of_birth

The date format for the Date_of_birth column is dd-mm-yyyy

As far as I know the default format for the date datatype in SQL is yyyy-mm-dd

How do I specify this alternate date format inside the create table command ? So, that when I insert value into the table I can insert in the dd-mm-yyyy format.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't.  You handle that in your display code.

Comment: @DanBracuk So, when I insert values into the table, I follow the default format to enter the values but I can have the required format only in the output. Right ?

Comment: If it's a for-real date datatype, your SQL engine will store it in a completely different format than what it is you enter (it will probably look like a strange number). A format would only apply if you were storing it as some sort of text format, which is definitely not the way you want to store a date. Yes, use output display to format the date.

Comment: And to answer your question, if your SQL server can interpret your input string as a date, it will store it correctly. You can change it on your insert query if you need to. `yyyy-mm-dd` is a fairly standard database representation of a date, but the interpretation will also depend on your database's localization.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A date has no format. You can format it as you wish when rendering it as a varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL (and most other RDBMS as far as I know) use `YYYY-MM-DD` as the standard string representation and cannot be changed. Any data inserted into such a field must be formatted in this manner, or converted to a true date value using functions such as [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).

Similarly, selecting a values from a field actually returns datetime types in most client languages, which can then be formatted as needed; or other date functions can be used in the select expressions to yield the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored internal so formatting is for input and output.

This will convert to the style you want for output:

```
 select convert(varchar(10), Date_of_birth, 105)    from Table
```